# REXML - How to extract a single element

Tags: ruby, rexml

I am writing some acceptance tests in ruby which involve asserting the presence of values in response XML.

My XML is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<file xmlns:dvi=xxxxx>
    <name>whatever</name>
</file>
```

There are other attributes but what is above should illustrate my point. Here is my ruby code:

```
xml = <the xml above>
xmlDoc = REXML::Document.new(xml)
puts xmlDoc.elements().to_a('file/name')
```

This prints out `<name>whatever</name>` but I want it to simply print out `whatever`

In this XML there will only ever be one name element. I have been able to print out just the text I want using `elements.each` but it seems like overkill.

Thanks,
Adrian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
xmlDoc.elements().to_a('file/name').first.text
```

and then add some error treatment (this is not robust).

The `to_a` returns an array of REXML elements. With `first` you retrieve the
first (and supposedly the only) element. With `text` you access that elements text content.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. For this particular test there will only be one name (It's getting metadata of a file). I have other tests where more than one elements will be returned but I think I know what to do now. Thanks again.