# Output array of tag contents using REXML?

Tags: ruby, xml

This has been asked before in "[REXML - How to extract a single element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347218/rexml-how-to-extract-a-single-element/7347278#7347278)" but the answer doesn't work.  Apparently, the `text` method is no longer available.

I have an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ice_cream>
    <flavor>Vanilla</flavor>
</ice_cream>
```

and I can place its contents into an array using REXML:

```
flavors = xml_file.get_elements('//flavor')
```

I get an array:

```
puts flavors[0]
```

Which returns:

```
<flavor>Vanilla</flavor>
```

Instead, I want:

```
Vanilla
```

I've tried:

```
flavors = xml_file.get_elements('//flavor').text
```

But, I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `text' for #<Array:0x007fa7a3b94220>
```

What's the correct way to accomplish this?  I'm open to using other libraries, too.

Comment: did you try `flavors[0].text`

Comment: Just give me the `xml` content please

Comment: No (shows you I'm a Ruby beginner).  That did the trick for pulling out the text from the array, but how do I get just the text into the array in the first place?

Comment: edited with example xml

Comment: added error message for text method.

Comment: @jcarpio Can you now tell, what else you are looking for ?

Comment: So, REXML will give me a collection of REXML::Elements.  And, I'll have to loop through and extract the text on my own?  I was hoping REXML would do this for me.

Comment: @jcarpio Yes, you have to.. That's quite obvious.

Comment: Why are you using REXML? Nokogiri will run circles around it, and is the de facto standard for HTML/XML parsing in Ruby.

Comment: First hit on google for "ruby xml parsing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org). Your code will thank you.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ice_cream>
    <flavor>Vanilla</flavor>
</ice_cream>
EOT

doc.search('flavor') # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3feb8182fc60 name="flavor" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3feb8182fa44 "Vanilla">]>]
doc.search('flavor').map(&:text) # => ["Vanilla"]
```

`search` finds all nodes, as a NodeSet, that match the CSS selector `'flavor'`.

`search('flavor').map(&:text)` walks the NodeSet and applies (`map`) the `text` method to each Node, returning its text node(s).

If your XML is actually something more complex:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ice_cream>
    <flavor>Vanilla</flavor>
    <flavor>Chocolate</flavor>
    <flavor>Strawberry</flavor>
</ice_cream>
EOT

doc.search('flavor') # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fcc2a577afc name="flavor" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fcc2a5778e0 "Vanilla">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fcc2a5776c4 name="flavor" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fcc2a5774bc "Chocolate">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fcc2a5772b4 name="flavor" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fcc2a572c78 "Strawberry">]>]
doc.search('flavor').map(&:text) # => ["Vanilla", "Chocolate", "Strawberry"]
```

Or:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ice_creams>
  <ice_cream>
      <flavor>Vanilla</flavor>
  </ice_cream>
  <ice_cream>
      <flavor>Chocolate</flavor>
  </ice_cream>
  <ice_cream>
      <flavor>Strawberry</flavor>
  </ice_cream>
</ice_creams>
EOT
ice_cream = doc.search('ice_cream') # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe6a91f6b00 name="ice_cream" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe6a91f68f8 "\n      ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe6a91f681c name="flavor" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe6a91f6600 "Vanilla">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe6a91f63f8 "\n  ">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe6a91f1de4 name="ice_cream" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe6a91f1bdc "\n      ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe6a91f1ac4 name="flavor" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe6a91f1880 "Chocolate">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe6a91f1678 "\n  ">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe6a91f13f8 name="ice_cream" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe6a91f1074 "\n      ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe6a91f0e80 name="flavor" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe6a91f0a98 "Strawberry">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe6a91f0840 "\n  ">]>]
ice_cream.search('flavor').map(&:text) # => ["Vanilla", "Chocolate", "Strawberry"]
```

For searching, Nokogiri supports using both CSS and XPath selectors, and allows you to use either in the methods, if you want. `search` accepts both CSS and XPath, and has corollaries of `css` and `xpath` for the CSS or XPath specific methods. `at` returns a single Node and is similar to `search('some_node').first` and has `at_css` and `at_xpath` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code :

```
require 'rexml/document'

doc = <<-xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ice_cream>
    <flavor>Vanilla</flavor>
</ice_cream>
xml

xml_doc = REXML::Document.new(doc)
xml_doc.get_elements('//flavor').class # => Array
xml_doc.get_elements('//flavor')[0].class # => REXML::Element
xml_doc.get_elements('//flavor')[0].text # => "Vanilla"
```

Actually `xml_doc.get_elements('//flavor')` will give you the collection of [`REXML::Element`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/REXML/Element.html#method-i-get_elements) objects. You then need to iterate through the collection and call the method [`#text`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/REXML/Element.html#method-i-text) on the `REXML::Element` object to get the text.